# How to select a node of treeview programmatically in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Used `treeview.SelectedNode` to select a child node. How to invoke `treeview.AfterSelect` event when a node is selected programmatically?

```
this.treeView1.SelectedNode = this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0]; 
if (this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].IsSelected) 
{
 MessageBox.Show("Node is selected"); 
}
```

Comment: You'll find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx).

Comment: It didnt work in my case.....

Comment: AfterSelect fires whether you select the node in code or the user does it.  Post better repro code.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Apologies for my previously mixed up answer.

Here is how to do:

```
myTreeView.SelectedNode = myTreeNode;
```

---

### (Update)

I have tested the code below and it works:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("1", "1");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("2", "2");
        treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("1-1", "1-1");
        TreeNode treeNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("1-2", "1-3");
        treeView1.SelectedNode = treeNode;
        MessageBox.Show(treeNode.IsSelected.ToString());
    }


}
```

Comment: I have tried selecting a node aas you said but it is returning as false when I called isSelected() of that node after it was selected..

Comment: Iam adding nodes and selecting them in the constructor so failed to invoke afterselect event. Got my mistake.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, constructor is not quite the same as Form Load.

Comment: Something I learned was that when you select the node programatically and it doesn't appear selected (blue) it's possible due to the treeview not being the active control.

Comment: Thank you - following the `SelectedNode` setter with a call to `treeView1.Focus()` makes this work great

Answer (score 5):

```
treeViewMain.SelectedNode = treeViewMain.Nodes.Find(searchNode, true)[0];
```

where searchNode is the name of the node.
I'm personally using a combo "Node + Panel" where Node name is Node +  and the same tag is also set on panel of choice.
With this command + scan of panels by tag i'm usually able to work a treeview+panel full menu set.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Because this question already have several answers, consider adding details to your answer as to why your answer and not one of the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `TreeView.OnAfterSelect()` protected method after you programatically select the node.

Comment: Maybe you meant "hook to AfterSelect event..."

Answer (score 0):

`yourNode.Toggle();` //use that function on your node, it toggles it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now and managed it this way.

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;
foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
{
    if(node.Text == "My Nodename")
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode = node;
        treeView1.Select();
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
TreeViewItem tempItem = new TreeViewItem();
TreeViewItem tempItem1 = new TreeViewItem(); 
tempItem =  (TreeViewItem) treeView1.Items.GetItemAt(0);    // Selecting the first of the top level nodes
tempItem1 = (TreeViewItem)tempItem.Items.GetItemAt(0);      // Selecting the first child of the first first level node
SelectedCategoryHeaderString = tempItem.Header.ToString();  // gets the header for the first top level node
SelectedCategoryHeaderString = tempItem1.Header.ToString(); // gets the header for the first child node of the first top level node
tempItem.IsExpanded = true;         //  will expand the first node
```

Answer (score -3):

```
private void btn_CollapseAllAndExpandFirstLevelUnderRoot(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    //this example collapses everything, then expands the first level under the root node.

    tv_myTreeView.CollapseAll();
    TreeNode tn =  tv_myTreeView.Nodes[0];
    tn.Expand();
}
```